# Showing new branch on bitbucket created in android studio without changing code

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

I created new branch for my project in Android Studio using **New Branch** inside **Git Branches**.But this branch doesn't show on bitbucket unless i commit and push.I have no changes to commit but I want to show it on bitbucket so others can create pull request to it.How can i show it on bitbucket without changing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to push the code in the remote branch so that they will be reflected in bitbucket.

To push your code from android studio, use the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + K` and choose the required branch for the commits to be pushed, then push it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

After press CTRL +SHIFT +K  you see above popup where you can easily change branch as you want and push code in the corresponding branch